# Powercenter SQL1224N error connecting DB2

Tags: db2, informatica-powercenter

Im running a workflow in powercenter that is constatnly getting an SQL1224N error.

This process execute a query against one table (POLIZA) with 800k rows, it retrieves the first 10k rows and then it start to execute to another table with 75M rows, at ths moment in DB2 an idle thread error appear but the PWC process still running retrieving the 75M rows, when it is completed (after 20 minutes) the errros comes up related with the first table:

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1224N  A database agent could not be started to service a request, or was terminated as a result of a database system shutdown or a force command.  SQLSTATE=55032
 sqlstate = 40003
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1224N  A database agent could not be started to service a request, or was terminated as a result of a database system shutdown or a force command.  SQLSTATE=55032
 sqlstate = 40003

Database driver error...
Function Name : Fetch
SQL Stmt : SELECT POLIZA.BSPOL_BSCODCIA, POLIZA.BSPOL_BSRAMOCO
FROM POLIZA
WHERE
EXA01.POLIZA.BSPOL_IDEMPR='0015' for read only with ur
Native error code = -1224
DB2 Fatal Error].
```

I have a similar process runing against the same 2 tables and it is woking fine where the only difference I can see is that the DB2 user is different.

Any idea how can i fix this?

Regards

Comment: change to the user that is working?

Comment: If the only difference is the user ID, then it's possible that the DB2 workload manager or Query Patroller terminates the session for some policy violation. In any case, talk to your DBA.

Comment: The working user id is sending the same error with this process but not with the old one. Could be something in the Powwercenter connection itself?

Answer (score 0):

The common causes for -1224 are:

- Your instance or database has crashed, or
- Something/somebody is forcing off your application (`FORCE APPLICATION` or equivalent)

As for the crash, I think you would know by know. This typically requires a database or instance restart. At any rate, can you please have a look into your DIAGPATH to check for any FODC* directories whose timestamp would match the timestamp of the -1224 errors?

As for the FORCE case, you should find some evidence of the -1224 in db2diag.log. Try searching for the decimal -1224, but also for its hex representation (0xFFFFFB38).